# Why assume probability is the square of error?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, history, probability, statistics

I'm an amateur trying to grasp Maxwell's [original derivation](http://www.ffn.ub.es/luisnavarro/nuevo_maletin/Maxwell_1860_Equilibrium_distribution.pdf) of gas particle velocity probabilities. This led me to Herschel's review of Quetelet, which Maxwell may or may not have been directly inspired by. Herschel's [informal description](https://books.google.com/books?id=bCP8DRF3eVYC&lpg=PA10&dq=error%20law%20derivation%20herschel&pg=PA10#v=onepage&q=error%20law%20derivation%20herschel&f=false) got me over the hump, mostly. I can now see how randomness leads directly to the need for the exponential function.

However, I'm less sanguine about the step in which Herschel declares that, to avoid negative numbers, the probability must be a function of the square of the error. Why not just use (e.g.) absolute value (which of course would lead to the wrong answer) instead of square?

My question is: is there some math/physics intuition I just don't have that makes the square the "obvious" choice in this situation, or is it that Herschel simply knew what the right answer was already via a more rigorous derivation and just reached for the simplest justification in this "dumbed down" explanation meant for the common man? Or, if that's too speculative to make a good question, then how about simply: why does it have to be the square instead of the absolute value?

Comment: -1. I think this is a question about either (a) mathematics (probability, error analysis) rather than physics (statistical mechanics), or (b) the history of science. Why do you think this is a question about present-day physical theory, as opposed an historical argument or a mathematical issue? ... Please can you be more specific about your link to Maxwell's derivation : which page and paragraph are you referring to?

Comment: isn't the absolute value of the error a function of the square?

Comment: You can view Maxwell's derivation as surrounding context and ignore it for simplicity. Since I don't know the answer to my question, I probably am not an expert in how best to categorize it. Clearly, people making relatively intuitive arguments related to error functions assumed that the probability was a function of the square of the error -- that's the assumption I'm trying to understand. OTOH, if there is an equally trivial and intuitive derivation of $A\e^{Bx^2}$ that would be great.  Hmm, is abs(x) a function of x^2? I guess I'm not getting how that could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got around to reading the quaint English in "Herschel's review of Quetelet" mentioned in your link. @Phoenix87 has already answered your question: $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$.

Also their interpretation of probability and statistics, as a procedure of arriving at best possible decisions (in the sense of being unbiased) in the face of our own uncertainty and ignorance, was heartwarming, because it is so close to E.T. Jaynes view of probability, which I really like. You may like to read entropy maximization procedure in E.T. Jaynes work on statistical mechanics/thermodynamics, or his book *Probability theory: Logic of science*.

------Previous answer------

I know nothing of "Herschel's review of Quetelet". My answer to your question is on general grounds.

You may quantify error by either its absolute value, or its square, or any function that is positive and monotone increasing (such as for example, by even powers). In fact people have argued that, when dealing with error, taking absolute value is better than squaring (see *Black Swan* by N.N. Taleb, in which he argues against standard deviation which is nothing but square-root-mean of squared error), on the grounds that squaring operation gives more than proportionate weight to larger errors than smaller ones while absolute values do not face this problem. I think the ubiquitous use of squaring the error has to do with the ease it provides in subsequent mathematical analysis.

Comment: Thanks, maybe that is the best that can be said. Unfortunately, choosing any of the other functions besides the square does not lead to a Gaussian curve.

Comment: Yeah, I have many hours in of reading Jaynes, with varying degrees of comprehension. I see with some Googling that apparently mathematicians mean "principal" square root when they write that symbol, which I guess is how one ends up saying that absolute value can be a function of (that definition of) square root. I'll mark this answer accepted and assume I don't know the right words or right place to post to elicit an answer to the key question about Herschel/Maxwell's derivation of the bell curve: justifying the choice of square (only right answer) over any other sign-removing function.